# Why does a multiprocessing process do the same job twice as long?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am doing some image analyzer within Blender and want to use multiprocessing in order to reduce calculation time. But when I split a list of pixels values into 4 parts between 4 processes, each of which then copy its list inside an invoked function, it turns out that one multiprocessing process do its work on copied list slower than an single process. Why is it so? I have Pentium G4620 with 2 cores and 4 logical processors. And I have to add, when I split the list into 2 parts, the difference is not as significant but nevertheless remains (~5 and ~6.2 sec for a single and a multi- process respectively).

```
from time import time

def modify(pixels): 
    this_pixels = list(pixels)[:]

    start = time()
    for j in range(1000): # in order to do something
        for i in range(len(this_pixels)):
            this_pixels[i] = 1.0
    end = time()
    print(__name__, 'Time for computing the copied list:', round(end-start,2), 'len of list:', len(this_pixels))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import bpy
    import sys

    sys.executable = bpy.app.binary_path_python
    __file__ = bpy.data.texts[0].filepath

    from multiprocessing import Process

    D = bpy.data

    img = D.images[0]
    pixels = img.pixels[:]

    pixels1 = img.pixels[:int(len(pixels)/4)]
    pixels2 = img.pixels[int(len(pixels)/4):int(len(pixels)/2)]
    pixels3 = img.pixels[int(len(pixels)/2):int(len(pixels)*3/4)]
    pixels4 = img.pixels[int(len(pixels)*3/4):int(len(pixels))]

    p1 = Process(target=modify,args=(pixels1,))
    p2 = Process(target=modify,args=(pixels2,))
    p3 = Process(target=modify,args=(pixels3,))
    p4 = Process(target=modify,args=(pixels4,))

    start = time()
#    modify(pixels1)
#    modify(pixels2)
#    modify(pixels3)
#    modify(pixels4)

    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p3.start()
    p4.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    p3.join()
    p4.join()
    end = time()

    print('Overall time:', round(end-start,2))
```

And the result for ordinary processing and multiprocessing respectively
:

```
    __main__ Time for computing the copied list: 2.5 len of list: 66000
    __main__ Time for computing the copied list: 2.52 len of list: 66000
    __main__ Time for computing the copied list: 2.52 len of list: 66000
    __main__ Time for computing the copied list: 2.52 len of list: 66000
    Overall time: 10.08

    __mp_main__ Time for computing the copied list: 4.86 len of list: 66000
    __mp_main__ Time for computing the copied list: 4.87 len of list: 66000
    __mp_main__ Time for computing the copied list: 4.8 len of list: 66000
    __mp_main__ Time for computing the copied list: 4.68 len of list: 66000
    Overall time: 5.63
```

EDIT:
Well, it's interesting. In another similar test, the most significant overall speed-up occurs, if there is splitting between two processes, this took 8.65 sec (compared to 13.88 sec for a single process). Between three processes - 7.66 sec, and between four - the same as for three.

And while there are no benefits of processing with three or four processes, the difference in cpu utilization is significant - 75% and 100% respectively.

Comment: What is the workload of the processors during execution? 100%?

Comment: ~30%(single) and ~100%(multi). Minus a few percent (3-5%) of regular utilization.

Comment: Generally if the program (1 process) doesn't max one processor then multiprocessing is not the right tool to Speed it up with multiple cores. The bottleneck is somewhere else. But it's odd that it is so much slower.

Comment: You are doing the processing just for a single image. Have you tried to scale this up? It is hard to tell, but maybe the multiprocessing introduces a big overhead and you get to see its benefits just for bigger datasets.

Comment: @OleksiyPlotnyts'kyy Could you provide an copy&pastable input that resembles your image? For example if it's a list containing integers then something like `[0] * 1000` (creates a list of thousand zeros) or if it's a NumPy array containing integers then `np.zeros(1000, dtype=int)` with the appropriate size? That way others would be able to confirm your results. I just wanted to run your example (instead of some examples I thought of) and couldn't because I don't have `bpy` nor the file. If you could check if the file is really loaded into memory (not just memory-mapped) that would be cool.

Comment: @MSeifert It's a long list that contains float rgba numbers of every pixel. How can I copy&past this to you?

Comment: Since the values don't matter just use 0, for example `[0.0] * size` (or whatever reflects the structure).

Comment: The same result for zeros only.

Comment: Could you update your question then with the zero input?